# How do change Font Awesome 5 icon colour?

Tags: html, css

```
<i class="fa fa-windows" style="font-size:200px;"></i>
```

I have this css:

`.fa fa-windows {
  color: 00DDFF;
}`

however the colour doesnt seem to change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.fa.fa-windows`

Comment: didnt work. :(.

Comment: Your selector is wrong, and the color value is invalid

Answer (score 0):

```
i.fa.fa-windows {
  color:red;
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, then some your other css rule is override it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.fa-windows {
  color: #00DDFF !important;
}
```

Comment: ohh I didnt see the `#` 

`.fa-windows {
  color: #00DDFF;
}`

this is correct

if that is not working try to use this 

`.fa-windows {
  color:#00DDFF !important;
}`

Comment: You can click on the edit button above and update your answer with the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.
When you are using two classes in order to select an element don't keep spaces between those classes.

.fa .fa-windows  - This is wrong. 
.fa.fa-windows - This is right.

```
<style type="text/css">


.fa.fa-windows {
  color: #00DDFF;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing # sign in color code and (.) in class. please try this code below:

```css
.fa.fa-windows {
    color: #00DDFF !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-windows" style="font-size:200px;"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong and for the hexadecimal code color you have to add the character '#', try this:

```
.fa-windows {
  color: #00DDFF;
}
```